# Why do runes bug out in Python 3.x?

Tags: python

I seem to have run into a problem with Python 3.x. I don't know if earlier versions would work this out correctly, but I inputted this code and got this response out of the console.

Code:

```
#Preset Variables
a=0
b=-1
c=None
d=None
e=-1
x=None
data=None
EorD=None
rune_req=None
```

There were two other rune variants that aren't important here.

```
#Younger Futhark Runes - ᛅᛒᚴᛏᛁᚠᚴᚼᛁᛁᚴᛚᛘᚾᚬᛒᚴᚱᛋᛏᚢᚢᚢ ᚴᛋ ᛁᛋ
def Younger_Encode():
    data=input('What would you like to encode?  ')
    data=data.lower
    for x in list(range(len(str(data)))):
        data=str(data).replace('a', 'ᛅ')
        data=str(data).replace('b', 'ᛒ')
        data=str(data).replace('p', 'ᛒ')
        data=str(data).replace('c', 'ᚴ')
        data=str(data).replace('k', 'ᚴ')
        data=str(data).replace('q', 'ᚴ')
        data=str(data).replace('g', 'ᚴ')
        data=str(data).replace('d', 'ᛏ')
        data=str(data).replace('t', 'ᛏ')
        data=str(data).replace('y', 'ᛁ')
        data=str(data).replace('j', 'ᛁ')
        data=str(data).replace('i', 'ᛁ')
        data=str(data).replace('e', 'ᛁ')
        data=str(data).replace('f', 'ᚠ')
        data=str(data).replace('h', 'ᚼ')
        data=str(data).replace('l', 'ᛚ')
        data=str(data).replace('m', 'ᛘ')
        data=str(data).replace('n', 'ᚾ')
        data=str(data).replace('o', 'ᚬ')
        data=str(data).replace('r', 'ᚱ')
        data=str(data).replace('s', 'ᛋ')
        data=str(data).replace('z', 'ᛋ')
        data=str(data).replace('u', 'ᚢ')
        data=str(data).replace('v', 'ᚢ')
        data=str(data).replace('w', 'ᚢ')
        data=str(data).replace('x', 'ᚴᛋ')
        print(data)
def Rune_Nav_En():
    if rune_req=='Anglo-Saxon Runes':
        Anglo_Encode()
    if rune_req=='Elder Futhark Runes':
        Elder_Encode()
    if rune_req=='Younger Futhark Runes':
        Younger_Encode()
```

This is first executed code. I'm omitting the 'decode' segment to save space. It's exactly the same at this point in the development process, because I haven't gotten around to working on that part yet.

```
while rune_req is None:
    EorD=input('Decode or Encode? ')
    if EorD=='Encode':               #Encoding runes
        while rune_req=='types' or rune_req is None :
            rune_req=input('Which rune type are you converting? Enter "types" to view available rune types. ')
            if rune_req=='types':
                print('                             +-----------------------+')
                print('                             |     Rune   Types      |')
                print('                             +-----------------------+')
                print('                             |   Anglo-Saxon Runes   |')
                print('                             |  Elder Futhark Runes  |')
                print('                             | Younger Futhark Runes |')
                print('                             +-----------------------+')
            if rune_req!='Anglo-Saxon Runes' and rune_req!='Elder Futhark Runes' and rune_req!='Younger Futhark Runes' and rune_req!='types':
                print('That is not an available rune type. Please enter "types" to see a list of available rune types.')
        Rune_Nav_En()
    if EorD=='Decode':               #Decoding runes
    if EorD!='Encode' and EorD!='Decode':
        print('You must input "Decode" or "Encode"!')
print('All Done!')
```

Console Response (with inputs):

```
Decode or Encode? 
-- Encode
Which rune type are you converting? Enter "types" to view available rune types. 
-- types
                             +-----------------------+
                             |     Rune   Types      |
                             +-----------------------+
                             |   Anglo-Saxon Runes   |
                             |  Elder Futhark Runes  |
                             | Younger Futhark Runes |
                             +-----------------------+
Which rune type are you converting? Enter "types" to view available rune types. 
-- Younger Futhark Runes
```

Up to here, the code works as expected.

```
What would you like to encode?  
-- This Test Worked
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
<ᛒᚢᛁᛚᛏ-ᛁᚾ ᛘᛁᛏᚼᚬᛏ ᛚᚬᚢᛁᚱ ᚬᚠ ᛋᛏᚱ ᚬᛒᛁᛁᚴᛏ ᛅᛏ 0ᚴᛋ7ᚠᛅ5ᛏ67756ᚴ0>
```

As you can see, the line is repeated over and over again. This is where the problem is. The line translates:

```
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x7fa5[t or d]67756[c, k, g, or q]0>
```

It repeats 26 times, which must mean it has something to do within `Younger_Encode()`. I don't know why. Can someone please help?

```
All Done!
```

Comment: you are missing parenthesis around `lower`

Comment: Awesome runes :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `for` loop in `Younger_Encode`.  You don't need it.  Do all the replacements and `print(data)` once.  Also missing parentheses after `data.lower`.

There is also a `str.translate()` function for strings to make this simpler, and `str.maketrans()` to build translation tables.

```py
# Build all the 1:1 translations
xlat = str.maketrans('abpckqgdtyjiefhlmnorszuvw',
                     'ᛅᛒᛒᚴᚴᚴᚴᛏᛏᛁᛁᛁᛁᚠᚼᛚᛘᚾᚬᚱᛋᛋᚢᚢᚢ')
# Add the two-character translation to the table.
xlat[ord('x')] = 'ᚴᛋ'

data='test string'
data=data.lower().translate(xlat)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
ᛏᛁᛋᛏ ᛋᛏᚱᛁᚾᚴ
```